# Need to dump autoload to everytime I add a new class

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I need to dump my autoloader every time I add a new class. I am using psr-4. I don't really know why I need to do so. In psr-4 it should automatically load the classes. Where am I going wrong?

Here's my composer.json file

```
{"autoload": {"psr-4": {"MyDomain\\": "app"}}}
```

Here's my directory structure:

[image]

Here's the code for one of my classes:

```
<?php

namespace MyDomain\Model;

class Employee {

}  
?>
```

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: And it finds and loads the classes after you run `composer dump-autoload`? Strange... It shouldn't find them. Do you, by chance, run `composer dump-autoload -o`?

Comment: Yes, I ran dump-autoload -o

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) (and also PSR-0) requires that the class `ClassName` is stored in a file named `ClassName.php`. The names are case sensitive and they must match exactly.

The file names in your project are lowercase, the class names are mixed case. The default disk formats on Windows and macOS are case-insensitive on search. This means when a program searches for `Employee.php` and the file `employee.php` exists in the directory, the search succeeds and the OS returns the existing file even if the case of its name is not the same as the case of the required file. On Linux-based OSes, the default disk format  is case sensitive and a program that searches for `Employee.php` cannot find `employee.php`.

Your `composer.json` file declares the `app/` directory as the root directory of the `MyDomain` namespace that follows the `PSR-4` standard. This is enough for the autoloader to find the file `app/Models/Employee.php` when it needs to load the class `MyDomain\Models\Employee`.

Because you run it on Ubuntu (which is a Linux-based OS), PHP cannot load the `Employee.php` file (because it doesn't exist) and the OS doesn't provide it the file `employee.php` instead.

It seems that you generate the autoloader using `composer update -o` or `composer dump-autoload -o`. The `-o` (short of `--classmap-authoritative`) tells Composer to scan the directories declared in `composer.json` (`app/`) in your case and create a classmap that contains all the classes it can find. A classmap is a list that maps the classnames (with the namespace) to filenames (with directories). This way, the autoloader knows exactly where to find each class and the loading goes faster.

The above two paragraphs explain why you need to regenerate the autoloader after you add a new class.

The correct way to do the job is to follow the [`PSR-4`](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) requirements. To be more specific, each namespace under `MyDomain` must be stored in a subdirectory of `app/` that has the same name, including the case. Each class must be stored in the correct subdirectory, in a file that has the same name as the class (including the case) and the termination `.php` (lowercase). For example, the class `MyDomain\Models\Employee` must stay in the file `app/Models/Employee.php`.

After you fix the file names you can run `composer dump-autoload` and forget about it. As long as the class and file names follow PSR-4 the autoloader will find them without regenerating it again.

On the production server you can run `composer dump-autoload -o` to improve its speed a little. Just don't forget to run it again after each deploy (or, even better, include the command in the deployment script).

Comment: It worked and thank you for a very clear and precise answer.